# Why does ExecuteNonQuery return 1 even if nothing was updated?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have a query like:

```
UPDATE messages SET Unread = 'N' WHERE id= '6'
```

To read affected rows, I use the value of `ExecuteNonQuery()`, but it always returns 1 even if nothing is changed. Saw the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5660383/1261657). Is this a bug or is this behavior normal?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns how many rows were *affected*, not changed. Is there a message with id = 6?

Comment: To rephrase what others have said, `...set name = 'foo' where name = 'foo'` affects the records where name = 'foo' even though the new value is no different than the old value.

Comment: Hmmm, so how then can one get *really affected* rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `ExecuteNonQuery` to return `1` there **must be** a record `WHERE id = '6'`. Now, if you **only want to update** the row if the value is different then change the query:

```
UPDATE messages SET Unread = 'N' WHERE id = '6' AND Unread <> 'N'
```

If you were to run that query and the value of `Unread` was already `'N'` then it would return `0` rows.

Answer (score 5):

The return value of `ExecuteNonQuery()` on an **UPDATE** query is the number of rows matched by the where clause of the update statement and **NOT** the number of rows actually updated. So it does make sense..

Please refer [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44194) link and all your doubts will be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the connection string option 'use affected rows'. When set to true it will report changed rows instead of found rows.

Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html